# Resource not found with c++builder android when using several jpg pictures

Tags: android

I get an error when I use Resource Pictures in C++Builder with Android.

```
int n = Random( 11 ) + 1;

String sPic = L"JpgImage_" + IntToStr( n );
TResourceStream *Stream = new TResourceStream( (int)HInstance, sPic, RT_RCDATA );  // Error Message here

//Image1->MultiResBitmap->LoadFromStream( Stream );
Image1->Bitmap->LoadFromStream( Stream );

Stream->DisposeOf();
```

Error message:
Exception-Klasse EResNotFound mit Meldung 'Resource JpgImage_2 not found'.

The same code works for win32, but not with android32 on 10.4.2

Has sombody any hints or tipps to get that running under android ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your solution view, click on the `<your name="">.rc` file to open the resource view.
Right click on the .rc file and select "Add Resource".
Now you will open a dialog box with options for Bitmap, Cursor, Icon etc.

You can also do Custom types as a BLOB, for example an embedded DLL.

Comment: Hi, sorry but I don't understand your message. Under "Projects->Resources and Pictures..." I added several JEPGs. They get id's like "JpgImage_1", and it works under win32. But when I switch the platform to android, I get the error.

Comment: Yes for mobile platform its different: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Resource_Files_Support